# Can OpenCV's VideoWriter write in a separate process?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to save a video to disk in a separate process. The program creates a buffer of images to save on the original process. When its done recording, it passes the file name and image buffer to a second process that will make its own VideoWriter and save the file. When the second process calls write, however, nothing happens. It hangs and doesn't output any errors.

I checked if the VideoWriter is open already and it is. I tried moving the code to the original process to see if it worked there and it does. I don't know if it is some setting I need to initialize in the new process or if it has to do with the way VideoWriter works.

Here's my code

```py
def stop_recording(self):
    """Stops recording in a separate process"""
    if self._file_dump_process is None:
        self._parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self._file_dump_process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=self.file_dump_loop, args=(child_conn, self.__log))
        self._file_dump_process.daemon = True
        self._file_dump_process.start()

    if self._recording:
        self.__log.info("Stopping recording. Please wait...")
        # Dump VideoWriter and image buffer to process

        # Comment out when running on main procress
        self._parent_conn.send([self._record_filename, self._img_buffer])
        """ Comment in when running on main procress
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
        effective_fps = 16.0
        frame_shape = (640, 480)

        record_file = cv2.VideoWriter(self._record_filename, fourcc,
                                      effective_fps, frame_shape,
                                      isColor=1)

        for img in self._img_buffer:
            self.__log.info("...still here...")
            record_file.write(img)

        # Close the file and set it to None
        record_file.release()
        self.__log.info("done.")
        """

    # Delete the entire image buffer no matter what
    del self._img_buffer[:]
    self._recording = False

@staticmethod
def file_dump_loop(child_conn, parent_log):
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
    effective_fps = 16.0
    frame_shape = (640, 480)
    while True:
        msg = child_conn.recv()
        record_filename = msg[0]
        img_buffer = msg[1]
        record_file = cv2.VideoWriter(record_filename, fourcc,
                                      effective_fps, frame_shape,
                                      isColor=1)
        for img in img_buffer:
            parent_log.info("...still here...")
            record_file.write(img)
        # Close the file and set it to None
        record_file.release()
        del img_buffer[:]
        parent_log.info("done.")
```

Here's the log output when I run it on one process:

```
2019-03-29 16:19:02,469 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: Stopping recording. Please wait...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,473 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,515 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,541 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,567 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,592 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,617 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,642 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: ...still here...
2019-03-29 16:19:02,670 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: done.
```

Here's the log output when I run it on a second process:

```
2019-03-29 16:17:27,299 - image_processor.stop_recording - INFO: Stopping recording. Please wait...
2019-03-29 16:17:27,534 - image_processor.file_dump_loop - INFO: ...still here...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and was successful with the following code:

```
import cv2
cap, imgs = cv2.VideoCapture('exampleVideo.MP4'), []

# This function writes video
def write_video(list_of_images):
    vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/stephen/Desktop/re_encode.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),120, (640,480))
    for image in list_of_images: vid_writer.write(image)

# Loop to read video and save images to a list
for frame in range(123):
    _, img = cap.read()
    imgs.append(img)
write_video(imgs)

cap.release()
```

Everything worked as expected, and when I checked how long it took to run, I found that the above code took .13 seconds to read the video and .43 seconds to write the video. If I read the video and write the video in the same loop (below) the total processing time is .56 seconds (which is .13+.43).

```
# Loop to save image to video
for frame in range(123):
    _, img = cap.read()
    vid_writer.write(img)
```

There is a big disadvantage of writing the images to a buffer (in memory) first, and then writing the images to a video file (on the hard drive). The buffer is saved on the RAM which will fill up very quickly, and you will likely get a memory error.